# API in return value for function

Tags: c, function, api, declaration

The following function declaration has an API preceding the return type:

```
NAMEOF_API void freeReplyObject(void *reply);
```

Can someone explain the details of this declaration, how to read it, how it differs from a declaration without the NAMEOF_API?

Comment: `NAMEOF_API` was likely created in a `#define`.  Find that definition to see what it translates to.

Comment: There will be a macro somewhere called `NAMEOF_API`. It is likely to be defined differently depending on whether some other macro is defined or not, at least for MS Windows DLLs.

Comment: In Windows, such a macro often declares the calling convention (e.g. __cdecl or __stdcall), or if this function is to be imported or exported from a DLL (e.g. __declspec(dllexport)).

Answer (score 0):

Thank you. The `#define` is `NAMEOF_API __declspec(dll**port)`. So, it declares the calling convention.